# Get multiple sub strings by matching pattern

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi I have a long string like this (just for here in real its so big ) `Error hasdashdkashdaskhdkha status:400 \n\t Error asdasdasdasdasdas status 404 \n\t`

and I want output something like this from this

```
1.  Error hasdashdkashdaskhdkha status:400
2.  Error asdasdasdasdasdas status 404
```

**for that I am doing something like this**

```
import re
mainString = "Error hasdashdkashdaskhdkha status:400 \n\t Error asdasdasdasdasdas status 404 \n\t"
start = re.escape("Error")
end   = re.escape("\n\t")

result = re.search('%s(.*)%s' % (start, end), mainString).group(1)

print(result)
```

and I am getting this **just**  `Error hasdashdkashdaskhdkha status:400` . kindly suggest how I can get both at same time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `re.findall` to find each occurrence. You can fine-tune the selection though, as you are selecting the whitespaces after `Error` and after the error code. See the output array.

```
import re
mainString = "Error hasdashdkashdaskhdkha status:400 \n\t Error asdasdasdasdasdas status 404 \n\t"
start = re.escape("Error")
end   = re.escape("\n\t")
result = re.findall('%s(.*)%s' % (start, end), mainString)

>>> result
[' hasdashdkashdaskhdkha status:400 ', ' asdasdasdasdasdas status 404 ']
```